# Using VIKOR multicriteria method in R

Tags: r, multicriteria-decision-analysis

I'm using the `VIKOR` multicriteria method from the `MCDM` package. The example can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCDM/MCDM.pdf

However, I would like a clearer explanation of this method. This is the example in the link above:

```
library(MCDM)

d <- matrix(c(1,2,5,3000,3750,4500),nrow = 3,ncol = 2)
> d
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1 3000
[2,]    2 3750
[3,]    5 4500

w <- c(0.5,0.5)

cb <- c('min','max')

v <- 0.5

VIKOR(d,w,cb,v)

> VIKOR(d,w,cb,v)
  Alternatives     S    R Q Ranking
1            1 0.500 0.50 1       2
2            2 0.375 0.25 0       1
3            3 0.500 0.50 1       3
```

I've seen that the `ranking` is based on `Q`, however from what I'm seeing the lowest value is the best, right? And I also didn't quite understand this value of `v`.

Could you explain me better about this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, lowest $Q$ wins. The weight $v$ is used to form a weighted average of $S$ (multiplied by $v$) and $R$ (multiplied by $1-v$). There is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIKOR_method) that attempts to explain VIKOR.